# How to track bounce email in drupal 9.d

Tags: drupal

How to track bounce email in drupal 9 and drupal 10.

I have tried lots of module but nothing found like i am using mail log send grid module but no help to track bouncing email.  Basically i am using view send module to send bulk email using smtp . but client want to check log which mail id delivered to  user or not.